# Scroll to a element with a specific class in an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have this div:

```html
<div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-row">
          <div class="grid-cell"></div>
          <div class="grid-cell"></div>
          <div class="grid-cell"></div>
          <div class="grid-cell"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-row">
          <div class="grid-cell"></div>
          <div class="grid-cell"></div>
          <div class="grid-cell"></div>
          <div class="grid-cell"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-row">
          <div class="grid-cell"></div>
          <div class="grid-cell"></div>
          <div class="grid-cell"></div>
          <div class="grid-cell"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-row">
          <div class="grid-cell"></div>
          <div class="grid-cell"></div>
          <div class="grid-cell"></div>
          <div class="grid-cell"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

that is opened in an iframe, and I want to have the iframe scroll to the div with class `grid-container` when it is loaded.
the iframe:

```html
<iframe style="position:absolute;border:none;width:100%;height:93%;" src="https://ovolve.github.io/2048-AI/" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this is useful for you. check this. in your iframe src files(which you added in iframe) write this js codes:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("grid-container")[0].scrollIntoView();
```

this is scrolling automatically to div which class name is `grid-container`.

Comment: How would I incorporate this into an external website that is out of my control?

Answer (score 0):

use `scrollTop` or `scrollTo(xcoord,ycoord)`.

```
<body>
    <iframe
      src="https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/"
      width="900px"
      height="1000px"
    ></iframe>
</body>

  <script>
    let myIframe = document.querySelector("iframe");
    myIframe.scrollTop = 1500;
  </script>
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to scroll within the iframe, I have updated my question to allow you to curate your answer more.